# How to format textfiles values retrieved from a directory and displayed in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

The problem now is how would I be able to format the values being displayed in datagridview from textfiles.

I have retrieved values from looping through textfiles removed the first two strings. Now I want to add separators or change the format of the displayed value like, for example:

```
textfile lines:          result:

01Sample     - line1      
022          - line2     
0306212019   - line3     06/21/2019
041234567890 - line4     12,345,678.90
```

I have already tried this one changing the defaultcellstyle but since the values are from textfiles in a directory its not affecting the output

```
DataGridView1.Columns("Gross Sales").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##,0"
```

```
Private Sub ReadTextFiles()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Date")
    dt.Columns.Add("Gross Sales")

    Dim Folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\test\")
    Dim lstLines As New List(Of String)


    For Each fileentries As String In Folder.GetFiles("s*",   IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Name).Select(Function(x) x.FullName)
        lstLines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(fileentries))
    Next


    Dim i As Integer
    Dim OuterLoopIterations As Integer = CInt(lstLines.Count / 22)
    For iterations = 0 To OuterLoopIterations - 1
        Dim row = dt.NewRow
        For col = 0 To 21
            row(col) = lstLines(i).Remove(0, 2) 'i have removed the first 2 characters of each string

                i += 1
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(row(2), row(5), row(12), row(13), row(14), row(15),  row(7), row(8), row(11))

    Next

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    'the code i tried applying
    DataGridView1.Columns("Gross Sales").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##,0"
```

this is my expected result

Current datagrid view: [image]

the result should be for date column: 06/07/2019
for the gross : 48,990.14

Edit:

I tried this one

```
Dim B As Double

Dim Folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\test\")
Dim lstLines As New List(Of String)


For Each fileentries As String In Folder.GetFiles("s*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Name).Select(Function(x) x.FullName)

    B = CDbl(Val(fileentries))
    lstLines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(B))
Next
```

Comment: That edit you made is completely nonsensical.  Why would you think that converting the path of the file to a number was a good idea, or even possible?  You need to convert the values that you read from the file into into numbers, and only the ones that actually represent numbers.  You need to read the data from the file, convert the parts of the data that need converting and then add that data to the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format something as a number then it has to be a number.  That means that, for example, if you read the text "1234.5" from the file and you want to display it as 1,234.50 in your grid then you have to convert the `String` you read to a `Double` or `Decimal`.  If you do that then the numeric format specifier you're using in the grid column will work.

Comment: hi. i tried something like this.                                                                           `Dim B As Double
 Dim Folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\megaworld\")
 Dim lstLines As New List(Of String)
        For Each fileentries As String In Folder.GetFiles("s*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Name).Select(Function(x) x.FullName)
            B = CDbl(Val(fileentries))
            lstLines.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(B))
        Next` but its not working.

Comment: Long code snippets are barely readable in comments.  Please edit your question if you need to add more code.